# Pandas, if two values are in two columns, but it doesn't matter which value is in which column

Tags: pandas

I would like to check if two columns in my pandas dataframe contain two values, but it doesn't matter which column the values are in.

I came up with this

```
df[

((
    df['Entity1'] == 'A'
) 
|
(
    df['Entity2'] == 'A'
))
&
((
    df['Entity1'] == 'B'
) 
|
(
    df['Entity2'] == 'B'
))

]
```

Whichs works, but I am not sure if it's the most efficient since it's checking each column twice.

Comment: It's probably pretty fast, but it's a little hard to read. Let me see if I can come up with something nicer...

Comment: kindly share sample dataframe with expected output

Comment: I've updated my answer with a simpler answer. Let me know if it works too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way by comparing swapped columns:

```
v = df.values
df[~(v == v[:, ::-1]).any(axis=1)]
```

Or even better if you simply want to drop rows having same element:

```
df[df["Entity1"].ne(df["Entity2"])]
```

Validation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([*"AB"], (10000, 2)), columns=["Entity1", "Entity2"])

# OP's method
c1 = df["Entity1"].eq("A")
c2 = df["Entity2"].eq("A")
c3 = df["Entity1"].eq("B")
c4 = df["Entity2"].eq("B")

new_df = df[((c1 | c2) & (c3 | c4))]

# This answer
v = df.values
new_df2 = df[~(v == v[:, ::-1]).any(axis=1)]

new_df.equals(new_df2)
# True

# This answer2
new_df3 = df[df["Entity1"].ne(df["Entity2"])]

new_df.equals(new_df3)
# True
```

Benchmark (up to 6x faster)

```
%%timeit
c1 = df["Entity1"].eq("A")
c2 = df["Entity2"].eq("A")
c3 = df["Entity1"].eq("B")
c4 = df["Entity2"].eq("B")

new_df = df[((c1 | c2) & (c3 | c4))]
# 1.86 ms ± 3.49 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit 
v = df.values
new_df2 = df[~(v == v[:, ::-1]).any(axis=1)]
# 447 µs ± 1.62 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df[df["Entity1"].ne(df["Entity2"])]
# 272 µs ± 1.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```